# Magento 1.7 Procedure 'catalogProductAttributeInfoRequestParam' not present

Tags: api, magento, soap, wsdl, magento-1.7

Official Magento's documentation syas that 1.x version has 'catalogProductAttributeInfo' API SOAP method. [image] I try to call API via SOAP for magento 1.7.0.2. But when i can this method i receive an error.

request:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <catalogProductAttributeInfoRequestParam xmlns="urn:Magento">
        <sessionId xmlns="">9629feea102e3c4df4eaaa1a73e45ef5</sessionId>
        <attribute xmlns="">manufacturer</attribute>
    </catalogProductAttributeInfoRequestParam>
</s:Body>
```

response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Procedure 'catalogProductAttributeInfoRequestParam' not present</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I see that there is no susch method in 1.7.0.2 wsdl. But this method works in magento 1.9.

**May be there is a patch for magento 1.7.0.2 ce which will add this method and force it works like magento 1.9.?
How to get attributeInfo for magento 1.7.0.2?**

**UPDATE 1**

raw request without a body :

```
POST https://www.mymagento.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: ""
Host: www.mymagento.com
Content-Length: 404
Expect: 100-continue
```

Comment: What URL are you calling?

Comment: @DouglasRadburn thanks for the question,  look into update 1